# Automatic sales tax for PayPal IPN?

Tags: php, paypal

I've configured the dummy/sandbox business with the applicable sales tax rates.  My IPN form builder provides PayPal with all the information it needs to calculate sales tax (destination country, state/province, postal/zip).

Does PayPal just not offer to automatically calculate sales tax, despite having everything it needs or am I missing something?  Maybe there's an IPN variable for "add sales tax", but I'm not finding it.

Comment: IPN stands for Instant Payment Notification, it's when PayPal contacts your site to notify you a payment has been made. By then the transaction is complete and any Tax has already been included.

Comment: @Styphon: thanks, I'm aware of IPN's function, but why shouldn't it be able to automatically add applicable sales tax when instructed and provided all the necessary information?

Comment: Because that's not the function of the IPN. You clearly aren't aware of the function of IPN, that's why I put it above. If you want tax to be calculated then you need to do that when making the initial submission to PayPal, not after the transaction is complete.

Comment: @Styphon: yes, it notifies a specified URL of a **specific** payment that it's been given from an application, along with data (which can include country/state/zip) and I'm struggling to think of any reason why it *can't* provide the *option* to automatically add applicable taxes, display it pre-payment summary screen and return the final amount to the application.

Answer (score 0):

Tax depends on where you are based. You need to set up the Sales Tax in your paypal account (eg 20% in the UK). This rate will then be applied to your sale (ie the customer will be charged price + tax). Both the Gross and Net prices will then be part of the IPN (Instant Payment Notification) for you to process.

Plenty of documentation about this on PayPal :

https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/shipping/EasyCalculateShipAndTax-outside

Comment: That's exactly what I did: I went to `Merchant Services > Tax calculator` in the PayPal sandbox business account, setup the domestic tax rates and put a **domestic** test order through, which included the country, state/province and zip/postal code.  No taxes were added by PayPal.

Comment: I've just got Login->Profile Summary->Value Added Tax->and set up the tax rates... The tax gets added automatically at the paypal page..

Comment: I imagine PayPal arranges and labels the menu items differently based on locale.  I'm in Canada.

Comment: In the US, tax depends on the state the customer is in. How is that handled with IPN if you're delivering electronically?